# Why does pow() in C++ Return a Negative Number

Tags: c++, pow, cmath

Using `pow()` from the `<cmath>` library, I get a negative number for some numbers.

```
2601*((int)pow(10.0,3*2)) = -1693967296
```

Why is this so? Is due to the fact that `int` only has a range between -32767 to 32767? Or is it because of the casting?

Comment: Int32 is wrapping around

Comment: integer overflow..the numbers are much bigger and it circles to a large negative number on overflow if the int is signed .

Comment: If you need to do this kind of computation without overflowing, you'll need to to Large Integer Arithmetic: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/djimenez/utsa/cs3343/lecture20.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour of your program is *undefined* as you are overflowing a signed integral type.

`pow(10.0, 3 * 2)` is *not* returning a negative number. That particular overload will return a `double`. You are casting that to an int then multiplying that by a constant. That is too big to fit into an `int`. Did you check `INT_MAX` (or the equivalent `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`)on your platform?

Comment: It looks to me like the return from pow does fit in an int and it's the multiplication that is overflowing.

Comment: You are correct. Thank you for pointing that out. I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the `pow()`, but you preempted the answer.

10 to the 6th power is a million, and a million times 2,601 is

```
2,601,000,000
```

For signed integers on your platform, the range is probably

```
–2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
```

So you see, you've exceeded that range. The actual overflow difference may seem inconsistent, but that's because of two's complement form.

Comment: Your range is true for a 2's complement 32 bit signed `int`.

Comment: Yes, this is true. I am making a (possibly wrong) assumption about the platform. But this is the most common, in my experience.

Comment: I know what you mean really, but if you said that on the C tag, you'd have the embedded system guys after you. But seriously, your assertion of the range ruins this answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of integer overflow.

```
2601*1000000 > INT_MAX.
```

Hence overflow.

Comment: Picky I know but INT_MAX ain't in `std`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is because of ***int*** data type. ***int*** range is from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, because ***sizeof(int)*** is 4 bytes.

To overcome this, you can use ***unsigned int*** or ***long int***

Comment: "int range is from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, because sizeof(int) is 4 bytes". Indeed that's correct sometimes. But the C++ standard does not insist on this. Worse than that, `unsigned` can be as small as 0 to 65535 so will not help in this case.

Comment: yeah. Unsigned can be 0 to 65535 in case of 16-bit compiler systems. But narrowing the above problem, questioner is using 32-bit compiler system. If you r free , have a look at this https://ideone.com/KZagQB :P

Comment: "long int" on many systems is no larger than int. "long long int" on the other hand is gauranteed to be at least 64 bits (and practically is exactly 64 bits).

Answer (score 0):

Your platform appears to have a 32-bit int. This supports a range of -2147483648 to 2147483647

pow() returns a positive number in a double precision floating point number. This bit works fine.

Your cast converts this to an int, again this is fine.

Where things go wrong is the multiplication. The multiplication overflows, signed overflow is undefined behaviour.

In your case you seem to have ended up with twos complement wraparound but you should be aware that this behaviour is not gauranteed, especially with modern optimising compilers.